# Which is the best way to implement Material Design menus in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-menu, material-design

Is there a standard way to implement material design menus?.
http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/menus.html#menus-simple-menus

I need to do something like the following picture:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0kFy.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally ended up using "pop up menus" of android, customizing them, so it looked somewhat like "material design".

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#PopupMenu

Comment: Yes. I understand, you confusion. Can you please mark this as answered?